Antd - Table component - Horizontal scroll bar position
I 'm using Ant Design's Table component to display a considerable number of rows per page. The problem I'm facing is that the horizontal scroll is way at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to position the horizontal scroll bar on the top of the Table, instead of default behavior which is at the bottom.
I tried the docs but nothing related showed up.
Thanks in advance!

There is no provision for scrollbar to be placed at top as per the documentation. https://ant.design/components/table#scroll

I faced the same problem, and there is no native way to do it with AntD, but it can be done using CSS rotateX, here's how I solved it:
/* Rotate ant-table-body & its children table. */
.ant-table-body,
.ant-table-body > table,
.ant-table-fixed-right, /* If you're also using fixed columns, rotate them too. Both the container ant-table-fixed-right/left & its children ant-table-body-outer. */
.ant-table-fixed-right > .ant-table-body-outer,
.ant-table-fixed-left,
.ant-table-fixed-left > .ant-table-body-outer {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

/* If you're using fixed columns, they will be misaligned with the rest of the table when the scroll bar is on top, so apply this to fix it. */
.ant-table-fixed-right,
.ant-table-fixed-left {
  height: 100%;
}

I took it from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-position-of-scrollbar-using-css/
And here's also a modified demo using this scroll top if you wanna try it first: https://codepen.io/laura-e24/pen/YzbWdxO

You have try it
.custom-table-container {
  direction: rtl;
 }

.custom-table-container .ant-table {
  direction: ltr;
}

.custom-table-container .ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.custom-table-container .ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.custom-table-container .ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}
.custom-table-container .ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

but I recommend using scroll X so that the width of the table is not too big compared to your screen

Have you tried activating the “sticky” feature in the ant design table structure instead of moving the scroll bar up?
<Table
  rowKey="id"
  scroll={{ x: "100%" }}
  sticky
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={users}
/>

When this feature is activated, you don't need to scroll to the bottom of the page. An extra scroll-bar structure is created at the bottom of the screen on the horizontal axis.
